# Select a class with a space character in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup and am attempting to select an html class with a space in its name:

```
<p class="story-body-text story-content" /p>
```

The usual method for class selection (.class) is not working in this instance. My code is:

```
Elements text = doc.select(".story-body-text story-content");
```

Which is returning an empty list of Elements. I have seen that I can perhaps try

```
Elements text = doc.select(".~story-body-text");
```

However, that is giving me troublesome source not found errors in eclipse, despite the fact that I have added the Jsoup jar into my project, so ideally there would be another solution as I can't seem to solve the source not found issue.

Comment: I guess, jsoup uses CSS selectors. If yes, then all of your selectors are wrong and it actually should be `doc.select(".story-body-text.story-content")`.

Comment: Not that it should matter for the answer, but there's a syntax error in your `<p>` tag - that last p before the `>` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#` is the prefix for an id. `.` is the prefix for a class name. When there is a space in the class attribute, it's considered as seperate class names.

I'd expect these to work:

```
Elements text = doc.select(".story-body-text");

Elements text = doc.select(".story-content");

Elements text = doc.select(".story-body-text.story-content");
```

Comment: Scratch that, had a different syntax error, solution works, thanks.

Comment: You could also do `[class="story-body-text story-content"]` - which finds that exact attribute value, instead of just having those two classes.